# Controlling default value of arcpy.AddField_management

Tags: python, arcpy, arcgis-10.1, cursor

I have a large collection of shapefiles that use text fields to hold numerical values.  I have created new fields, and populated them with the numerical equivalent of the text field.  When adding the new field using:

```
arcpy.AddField_management(fc, numField,"DOUBLE")
```

all rows are assigned a zero value.  My problem is that I have both zero values and nulls in my text field (nulls are represented by a single space), and they mean something different, but when I transfer the value of the text field into the numerical field, both zero and null appear as zero.
I've tried forcing the numerical field to null when I populate it using the else clause:

```
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, [strField, numField]) as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        tstField = re.findall("[0-9]", row[0])
        if len(tstField)>0:
            row[1] = round(float(row[0]), 1)
            cursor.updateRow(row)
        else:
            row[1] = ""
```

but this still leaves me with zeroes for nulls.

I know that the Double field type can contain nulls, so what am I missing/doing wrong?

I'm using ArcGIS 10.1

(I realize that the way I'm checking for nulls is clunky, but looking for spaces - even when copied and pasted from the table - gave no joy.  Using `re` let me check for numeric values)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
else:
    row[1] = None
```

None is what Python uses for Null.

I'm not very familiar with regex, so I'm going to suggest a different version of your cursor operations, see if this works:

```
for row in cursor:
    if row[0] == " ":
        row[1] = None            
    else:
        row[1] = round(float(row[0]), 1)
    cursor.updateRow(row)
```

The issue may simply have been where you had placed the `.updateRow()` method (always make it the last thing before going to the nest row).

Comment: Thanks.  I ran it using `null`, but still got zeroes.  I tested it using a dummy value (99) and still got zeroes, so I think the problem may be elsewhere in the script.

Comment: @markouellette: Your sample doesn't include an updateRow under the else condition, which is probably why you get 0 even when trying to use 99, but read my answer as to why you can't add nulls

Comment: Thanks; I moved the update after the else and it runs properly, aside from the null v shapefile issue mentioned by DWynne.
I originally tried the == " " approach, but for some reason it wouldn't find the cells with spaces.

Answer (score 2):

Shapefiles don't support nulls. Read the section 'Null value representation' here:
http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/manage-data/shapefiles/geoprocessing-considerations-for-shapefile-output.htm

If you really need to have nulls, consider migrating this data into a geodatabase.

Comment: Well, that's inconvenient.  Thanks for the info.  I'll stop beating my head against that particular wall.

Comment: I'd vote this answer up, but I don't have the reputation points for that yet.